# Google weather gadget/widget like the one on search

Tags: google-search

When searching for "weather " with google.com like http://www.google.com/search?q=weather+cupertino a formatted weather forecast with icons is shown before the first actual search result.
Is there a way to embed this into a Google site (sites.google.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

Google possibly sources these weather details from other service providers. You can consider using the [tools provided by The Weather Channel](http://www.weather.com/services/) (one of the links suggested for detailed forecasts in the Google's infographic) to embed a similar [Weather widget](http://www.weather.com/services/oap/weather-widgets.html?from=wxtools_WeatherWidget) within your own site.